# Getting the ID of a hotkey registered through RegisterHotKey

Tags: windows, hotkeys, registerhotkey, global-hotkey

I've seen posts about getting the process that owns a specific hotkey, but what if I already have access to the process' thread (e.g. DLL injection), and want to find the ID of a specific hotkey to call UnregisterHotKey on it? The stuff that I found relating to this was mostly outdated, and I've went as far as to decompile the executable's source, but since I'm relatively new to this, I've had no luck. Maybe there's some sort of convoluted way of finding the ID by brute force? Any help would be appreciated.